# Delayed sandbox attribute to iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, embed, sandbox

I'm currently facing to a problem. I'm triyng to embed an external player (like dood stream, vtube, etc) into my Reactjs app but these players have so many annoying ads... So i tried to block external links with some methods but it's not working...

What I tried :

- Sandbox the iframe but detected
- Parsing the html with a PHP script as proxy => JS script not loading because of CORS
- Edit the DOM inside the iframe => not working because of XSS security
- Reverse engineer the script that detect the sandbox attributes => It looks about the "Sandbox" attribute inside the window.parent and window.top
- Try with nested iframes/embed tag/obj tag etc. => sandbox detected

Actually, I'm trying to add sandbox attribute some seconds after the iframe is loaded, the embedded players does not detect it but, the iframe is not sandboxed and ads continue to pop... Someone can explain me why the sandbox attribute is not considered after the iframe is loaded ?

Comment: I have the same issue right now, did u find any fix?